# update kubernetes pod with new config

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

How I can Update the container that already running on kubernetes?
I have created my config-file.json and I want to apply this config file to the container that is running on kubernete.

Thank You

Comment: Does your container currently using the config file in the cluster or waiting to use your config-file.json?

Comment: They use the config file ,I wanna Kill this Pod and Deploy new one instead of the old one .